# Execute a function only after all Async functions executed in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

There are different answers around here on stack overflow but I still can't make it work on. Can someone let me know what the error or any better solution

```
array = [[name1,value1],[name2,value2] ;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    name = array[i][0];
    value = array[i][1];
    //the below is the async function in tableau javascript
    worksheet.applyFilterAsync(name, value, 'ADD')

    if (i = array.length - 1) {
       addEventListener = () => {
           callbackfunction();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Promise.all` ?

Comment: Have you tried searching your question title?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` to wait for all promises to resolve and rejects if at least one promise throws a rejection:

```
var array = [[name1,value1],[name2,value2]];

// .map returns an array of promises
var promises = array.map(([name, value], i) => {
    //the below is the async function in tableau javascript
    return worksheet[i].applyFilterAsync(name, value, 'ADD');
});

promises[promises.length - 1].then(() => {
    // Do stuff after the last promise is resolved
});

// Waits for all promises to resolve
Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // Do stuff after all promises are resolved
});
```

Comment: *if none reject.

Comment: `[name, value]` is called [array deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so you don't need to access the array via index.

Comment: Here, my array length is around 20 , so Promise.all //do my stuff executes 20 times, but I just need only time that too after last async function is executed.

Comment: Should the function be executed successfully or just started?

Comment: After execution

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope this fullfills your needs